# How to present own view controller just after launch screen in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I want to present the home screen if the user is already logged in, however I am not checking if the user is logged in or not. For this, I have written the code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function of AppDelegate but still loading the default controller.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let homeController = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeVC") as! HomeViewController
        let navC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeController)
        navC.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        navC.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController = navC
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
        return true
    }
```

Comment: probably there is still the default storyboard in main.storyboard.

Comment: how can I change this behaviour

Comment: in your project settings under general > Deployment Info > Main Interface delete "Main" and navigate to the Info.plist file on the left side. Under the keys, Application Scene Manifest > Scene Configuration > Application Session Role > Item 0 (Default Configuration), select the string “Storyboard Name” and delete it with the minus button.

Answer (score 0):

1.In your project settings under general > Deployment Info > Main Interface delete "Main".
2. Navigate to the Info.plist file on the left side. Under the keys, Application Scene Manifest > Scene Configuration > Application Session Role > Item 0 (Default Configuration), select the string “Storyboard Name” and delete it with the minus button.
3. There is a file named "SceneDelegate.swift" in your Project. There you have to put your code for loading the storyboard. (You used to do this kind of stuff in AppDelegate.swift but since ios13 we do that in SceneDelegate). You have to put the following code in the method "func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)":

```swift
guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(frame: windowScene.coordinateSpace.bounds)
        window?.windowScene = windowScene
let homeController = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeVC") as! HomeViewController
        let navC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeController)
        navC.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        navC.navigationBar.barStyle = .default
window?.rootViewController = navC
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

and remove your edits from AppDelegate.swift
[source](https://medium.com/swift-productions/ios-start-a-project-without-storyboard-xcode-12-253d785af5e7#0dd2)